# Goren Arvana/Ornan as the Location of the Temple

Tags: tanach, beis-hamikdash, king-david, book-of-chronicles, king-solomon

The last chapter of Samuel (24) describes King David's sin of counting the Jewish people and the resulting epidemic in which 70,000 Jews were killed. At the end of the account, the prophet describes how the angel administering the epidemic came to the threshing floor of Arvana (or Ornan as he is called in Chronicles) at the entrance to Jerusalem and pauses there before striking Jerusalem. King David buys the threshing floor and offers sacrifices to God there, after which the epidemic ends. In Chronicles 1,22 the story continues that King David prepared the place to be the site of the future Temple, and in Chronicles 2,3,1 it states that in fact King Solomon built the Temple there.

My question then is - what is the significance of the fact that the Temple was built in the place where the epidemic caused by King David's sin of counting the Jews ended? Why did God choose this place specifically as the site of the Temple?

Comment: "On Mount Moriah because the Holy One, blessed be He, appeared to David in the threshing floor of Ornan when the plague stopped, and that is Mount Moriah, David’s place." - Rashi's commentary on 2 Chr. 3:1

Comment: @Shmuel i don't see how that addresses the question

Comment: Why do you think that the epidemic ending was a cause for the temple to be there, instead of the fact that the temple was going to be there was the cause for the epidemic ending?

Comment: That spot was also the place of the akeida and Yaakov dream

Comment: It is also the place of Even Shisiah so it would definitely seem that the sacrifices offered in this place is what caused the epidemic to stop

Comment: @Chatzkel the ideas that you quote are all mentioned in midrashim, however not the the Tanach.